# Maybe get name of ObjectType in NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, nsarray, objective-c-runtime

I have custom class as below:

```
@interface TestObject : NSObject
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray<ObjA *> *obja;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *status;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *keyword;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) ObjB *objb;
@end
```

I want get ObjectType's name of property **obja** (which is **ObjArea**), but it only return NSArray. I had get name of class of other property include **objb**.  How can I get it **in runtime**? I have function get list property and class of them extend(category) NSObject like this.

```
- (NSArray *)propertyList {
    Class currentClass = [self class];
    NSMutableArray *propertyList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    do {
        unsigned int outCount, i;
        objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(currentClass, &outCount);

        for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
            objc_property_t property = properties[i];

            NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", property_getName(property)];
            [propertyList addObject:propertyName];
        }
        free(properties);
        currentClass = [currentClass superclass];
    } while ([currentClass superclass]);

    return propertyList;
}
```

and :

```
- (Class) classOfPropertyNamed:(NSString*)keyPath {
    Class class = 0;

    unsigned int n = 0;
    objc_property_t* properties = class_copyPropertyList(self.class, &n);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        objc_property_t* property = properties + i;
        NSString* name = [NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(*property) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (![keyPath isEqualToString:name]) continue;

        const char* attributes = property_getAttributes(*property);
        if (attributes[1] == '@') {
            NSMutableString* className = [NSMutableString new];
            for (int j=3; attributes[j] && attributes[j]!='"'; j++)
                [className appendFormat:@"%c", attributes[j]];
            class = NSClassFromString(className);
        }
        break;
    }
    free(properties);

    return class;
}
```

Comment: The question is too confusing to answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I had update question. Hope u understand. Thanks for supports.

Comment: Nope.  I don't have a clue what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should just set you custom object in the array then call

```
myCustomObject = [yourArray objectAtIndex:someIndex];
myCUstomObject.name // Then do what ever you want with it
```

or you could create a custom object of type NSArray like this:
[image]
then do this:
[image]
Then do what you want with your custom array